# Erased Windows 8 on purpose, leftovers interfering with new Ubuntu

Tags: windows, hard-drive, grub, bootloader

What I did:

1. Installed Windows 7
2. Installed Windows 8
3. Tried to install Ubuntu on 2x sliced partitions for software RAID. I installed it last because of grub.

   3a. I couldn't figure out how to create the tiny boot partition for efi, in Alt install.
   3b. I couldn't find "create partition of size" anywhere.
   3c. I gave up and erased Windows 8 to install Ubuntu.
4. Installed Ubuntu.
5. Windows 8 bootloader popped up again and asked me to "boot another OS". I happily clicked F9 or whatever.
6. Started booting Windows 7, and started screaming at my monitor.
7. Rebooted to repair mode install disk, reinstalled grub.
8. Nothing happened.

....

47. Did it again.
   48. Nothing happened.

Drives: (2x 2TB HDD WDCg) 1xEARS 1xEARX and 1x SSD 128 OCZVRTX4
Partitions: `/dev/sda1` = ntfs  `/dev/sda2` = Linux RAID 1/2 &
`/dev/sdb1` = blank, `/dev/sdb2` = Linux RAID

SSD = NTFS MBR (that can't be read in Linux for some reason)

Bonus question: Can I just put a bootloader a 1Gb USB stick?

Comment: What device did you install Ubuntu on? How did you partition it? Where are you installing Grub?

Comment: How did you erase Windows 8?

Comment: oh I just... system management -> disks -> /cyberman "delete!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption is that Win 8 formatted your drive to GPT.

IIRC, GRUB requires some mucking around to start from GPT, so you can either reformat with an MBR or use a process like [this](http://www.wensley.org.uk/gpt) to fake an MBR.